# re-direct to same url with parameters through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to re-direct few of Magento's sub-category urls to same url filtered with price high to low.

Ex: http://example.com/shoes/training.html 
should be re-directed to
http://example.com/shoes/training.html?dir=desc&order=price

My htaccess code is

```
302 /shoes/training.html http://example.com/shoes/training.html?dir=desc&order=price
```

Which indeed is re-directing to http://example.com/shoes/training.html?dir=desc&order=price but it gives a error that page isn't redirecting properly. Without my htaccess code http://example.com/shoes/training.html?dir=desc&order=price loads fine.

Issue is once the page is re-directed again it is finding `/shoes/training.html` in the url and trying to re-direct. How I can add the condition such that if complete url is found then we will re-direct otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

> How I can add the condition such that if complete url is found then we will re-direct otherwise not.

You will need to use `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^shoes/training\.html$ /$0?dir=desc&order=price [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure to keep this rule before other rules and clear browser cache while testing this.